# regex to add words inside parantheses if in list

Tags: python, regex

I am a beginner in python and regex. I have a list : `[cat,dog,bird,duck]`
If cat in list it should add 'animal' to existing pets() within paranthesis as :pets(animal)
If cat and dog in list,it should be : pets(animal,animal)

Text file:

```
My favourite pets
pets()
```

Expected Text file:

```
My favourite pets
pets(animal,animal)
```

Coding

```
import re
list=['cat','dog','bird','cow'] 
with open('te.txt','r+') as f:
    a = [x.rstrip() for x in f]
    if 'cat' in list:
        item='animal'
        add=(r'^pets (.*)', item)
        f.write('pets(' + item)
    if 'dog' in list:
        item='animal'
        add=(r'^pets (.*)', item)
        f.write('pets(' + item)
```

I have gone nuts doing this,please help me to fix my code.Answers will be appreciated!

Comment: you don't use regular expressions. And I don't see a point using them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sound like your find text in your file and replace it, your can use `str.replace` and rewrite it;

**Text file:**

```
My favourite pets
pets()
```

---

```
listAnimal = ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'cow'] 
with open('te.txt','r+b') as f:
    listsAppendAnimal = []
    text = 'pets('
    if 'cat' in listAnimal:
        listsAppendAnimal.append('animal')
    if 'dog' in listAnimal:
        listsAppendAnimal.append('animal')
    allText = f.read()
    allText = allText.replace('pets()', 'pets(' + ', '.join(listsAppendAnimal) + ')') # or use re python
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()
    f.write(allText)
    f.close()
```

---

**Output text file:**

```
My favourite pets
pets(animal,animal)
```

---

for use regex;

```
import re
listAnimal = ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'cow'] 
with open('te.txt','r+b') as f:
    listsAppendAnimal = []
    text = 'pets('
    if 'cat' in listAnimal:
        listsAppendAnimal.append('animal')
    if 'dog' in listAnimal:
        listsAppendAnimal.append('animal')
    allText = f.read()
    allText = re.sub(r'pets\(.*?\)', 'pets(' + ', '.join(listsAppendAnimal) + ')', allText)
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()
    f.write(allText)
    f.close()
```

--

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know why you’re using regular expressions. You can just read the text file, strip off the `My favourite pets` and `pets()` text with string slicing, construct your list and write it back out to the file. It’s not complicated enough to require regular expressions.

Here’s a quick alternative that I came up with:

```
MY_NEW_LIST = ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'cow']
ANIMAL_PETS = ['cat', 'dog']
PETS_FILE   =  'animals.txt'

# open the existing file, and get the line with `pets(…)`
with open(PETS_FILE, 'r+') as f:
    existing_animal_str = f.readlines()[1]

# get the list of animals from `pets(…)`
existing_animals = pets_line[5:-1]
list_of_animals  = [i for i in existing_animals.split(',') if len(i) > 0]

# add the new animals to the list
for pet in ANIMAL_PETS:
    if pet in MY_NEW_LIST:
        list_of_animals.append('animal')

# construct a new string to put back into `pets(…)`
final_animal_str = ', '.join(list_of_animals)

# write the new string back to the file
with open(PETS_FILE, 'w+') as f:
    f.write('My favourite pets\npets(%s)' % final_animal_str)
```

The first three lines contain some constants: the list of animals, the list of pets for which we add `animal` to the `pets()` line, and the name of the text file.

As a side note, your variable names could do with some work. As `list` is the name of a built-in function, and `add` is very generic, using variable names like this will cause problems down the line. Use more specific variable names.